# Intermittent NullReferenceException from EF4.3 Internal.AppConfig

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

We've been experiencing some issues with one of our online products returning a null reference intermittently, the stacktrace returned is below:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 at System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase.BaseGetAllKeys()
 at System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection.get_AllKeys()
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.Convert(NameValueCollection collection)
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig..ctor()
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig..cctor()
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at System.Data.Entity.DbContext..ctor(String nameOrConnectionString)
```

The product is using EF4.3 (I know we can upgrade, though I wanted to find the cause first) and seems to work most of the time so I'm not sure whether it's our code or not.

Has anybody has seen an issue like this, and/or know whether it has been fixed in a later version of EF?

Comment: Let me guess... you have a long-lived context accessed by multiple threads.

Comment: I didn't write the code, so I can only speculate but it doesn't seem to be.

The code does need to be thread-safe though as it can be accessed as a web service. I assume there is no issue with having multiple instances of DbContext accessing the app.config at the same time?

Edit - Should say it seems to construct a unit of work pattern and constructing instances each time. I'll try and get some code of the initialization of the objects to see if I'm understanding you correctly.

Comment: Contexts are not thread-safe, is all. Unpredictable exceptions in multi-threaded environments are often related to contexts that get hit by multiple threads.

Comment: Ahh okay so basically if we have any contexts as instance members that will be a problem? We should create local contexts whenever we have access to the db?

Comment: Well, at least have one context per thread, which for web apps usually is the same as context per request.

Comment: Ahh okay, it shouldn't be that. From what I can see all contexts are created on the fly at the top level, so where the code is threaded (web service level), each instance should be created for a each new call. Hmm, for something that is only calling a db with four tables I'm tempted to go back to SQL.

Comment: Quick question If I may, if the config files don't have any <entityFramework> blocks, is there any configuration within machine.config that this will refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looked like a EF bug, upgrading to the new version removed the problem.